# Register User using Angular 7 and core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am following a [tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/26/aspnet-core-21-simple-api-for-authentication-registration-and-user-management) on how to register users using angular 7 and a real net core 2.1 IIS Express server.

I get this error after I attempt to register on the client site:

```
POST https://localhost:44371/api/users/register 404
```

Here is the server controller users: (the rest of the code is at the link above)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using AutoMapper;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using RegisterLogin.Helpers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using RegisterLogin.Services;
using RegisterLogin.Dtos;
using RegisterLogin.Entities;

namespace RegisterLogin.Controllers
{
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUserService _userService;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public UsersController(
        IUserService userService,
        IMapper mapper,
        IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("authenticate")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]UserDto userDto)
    {
        var user = _userService.Authenticate(userDto.Username, 
userDto.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Username or password is 
incorrect" });

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_appSettings.Secret);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new 
 SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        // return basic user info (without password) and token to store 
 client side
        return Ok(new
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Username = user.Username,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Token = tokenString
        });
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public IActionResult Register([FromBody]UserDto userDto)
    {
        // map dto to entity
        var user = _mapper.Map<User>(userDto);

        try
        {
            // save 
            _userService.Create(user, userDto.Password);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (AppException ex)
        {
            // return error message if there was an exception
            return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var users = _userService.GetAll();
        var userDtos = _mapper.Map<IList<UserDto>>(users);
        return Ok(userDtos);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        var user = _userService.GetById(id);
        var userDto = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
        return Ok(userDto);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody]UserDto userDto)
    {
        // map dto to entity and set id
        var user = _mapper.Map<User>(userDto);
        user.Id = id;

        try
        {
            // save 
            _userService.Update(user, userDto.Password);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (AppException ex)
        {
            // return error message if there was an exception
            return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _userService.Delete(id);
        return Ok();
    }
  }
}
```

I can access the default values page. How may I display the users page?
When I type in https://localhost:44371/api/users I get a 404.

Here is the angular code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AlertService, UserService, AuthenticationService } from 
'../_services';

@Component({templateUrl: 'register.component.html'})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private alertService: AlertService
) { 
    // redirect to home if already logged in
    if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) { 
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: ['', Validators.required],
        lastName: ['', Validators.required],
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
    });
}

// convenience getter for easy access to form fields
get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.alertService.success('Registration successful', true);
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
}
```

Comment: That is an web api which will not return any page and it is annotated as HTTPPOST. You cannot access it in browser with a HTTPGET request.

Comment: Does `https://localhost:44371/users` work? I expect that it does, as that's the route you've configured with the routing attributes (there's no `api` prefix).

Comment: Kirk!  that is the answer!  Why didn't I see that?  Thanks.  It al works

Answer (score 0):

If you type https://localhost:44371/api/users/register on the URL you will not get some page.
In order to register the client in this case you will need to do an HTTP POST against that url with UserDto as http body.

if you are calling it from C#

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:44371/api/users/register" , usetDtoObject);
}
```